# How to convert all values to lower case to sort them

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following sort code and I want to be able to sort lower case values in data as well
right now this only sorts upper case values

```
 const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
const sortCallback = (prop: string, direction: string) => (
    a: object,
    b: object
  ) => {
  
    if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
      return direction === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
    }

    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
      return direction === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
    }

    return 0;
  };

  const sortData = (prop: string, direction: string) => {
    setData((data) => [...data].sort(sortCallback(prop, direction)));

    directionRef.current = {
      ...initDirection,
      [prop]: direction === "desc" ? "asc" : "desc",
    };
    activeRef.current = prop;
  };

  return { sortCallback, sortData, data, setData };
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const sortCallback = (prop: string, direction: string) => (
    a: object,
    b: object
  ) => {
  
    if (a[prop]. toLowerCase() < b[prop].toLoweCase()) {
      return direction === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
    }

    if (a[prop].toLowerCase() > b[prop].toLowerCase()) {
      return direction === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
    }

    return 0;
  };
```

let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you mean when you say it only sorts uppercase but you can use `.toLowerCase()` so that the string you are trying to compare to lower case.

Also I recommend you try using `.localeCompare()` function for comparing string.
Example of `localeCompare` with `toLowerCase`:

```
stringA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(stringB.toLowerCase())
```

- [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)
- [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the toLowerCase method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase